# Toolbar sethidden=TRUE, sethidden=FALSE

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, uitoolbar, ios5.1

I want to hide my toolbar if I click on a button, but it doesn't seem to work. I can hide the toolbar with an animation but I can't let it show up again. Thanks!

```
- (IBAction)hideTheToolBar{
    //[toolBar setHidden:YES];
    if (toolbar.hidden == NO)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                         animations:^(void)
         {
             toolbar.alpha = 0.0f;
         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             toolbar.hidden = YES;
         }
         ];
    }
    if (toolbar.hidden == YES) {
        toolbar.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: try also setting the alpha back to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think u are missing a statement in the second if loop try:

```
 if (toolbar.hidden == YES) {
    toolbar.hidden = NO;
    toolbar.alpha = 1.0f ;
}
```